# Using regex in for loop

Tags: bash, array

I'm looking to loop through a directory of files and match them with regex, then subsitute the appropriate character:

```
#somefile.txt
%somefile.txt
>somefile.txt

# arr=(\% \> \#) ;for f in *; do echo -- "$f" "${f//${arr[@]}/}"; done
```

should echo:

```
#somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
%somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
```

instead i get:

```
#somefile.txt -- #somefile.txt
%somefile.txt -- %somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- >somefile.txt
```

which results in no change, nada, zilch.

the array works if i use `arr(\%)` with a single character, which defeats the whole purpose.

```
#somefile.txt -- #somefile.txt
%somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- >somefile.txt
```

Comment: Minor note: I assume the double-hyphen is misplaced in the provided echo call?

Comment: the double-hyphen is just a separator during the echo if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core issue here is that the `${PARAMETER/PATTERN/STRING}` expansion `PATTERN` doesn't accept an array as `PARAMETER` does, and hence `${arr[@]}` expands to `"% > #"`.

The effect of this can be seen if you add a few files:

```
# touch "% > #somefile.txt"
# touch "%>#somefile.txt"
```

Your command would result in:

```
#somefile.txt -- #somefile.txt
%somefile.txt -- %somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- >somefile.txt
%>#somefile.txt -- %>#somefile.txt
% > #somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
```

The last line hopefully showing exactly what is going on.

Another has suggested using piping `$f` through `sed` and doing magic there, and that'd be a good option as it would allow for more complex transformations, however assuming that you only want to remove leading characters, using bash's `${PARAMETER#WORD}` [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) would suffice:

```
# gpat=" ;for f in *; do echo -- "$f" "${f#$gpat}"; done
```

For myself, that line results in:

```
>somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
#somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
%somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
%>#somefile.txt -- >#somefile.txt
% > #somefile.txt --  > #somefile.txt
```

I'm calling the pattern `$gpat` as that's what it is - a [bash globbing pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching). It's *not* a regular expression.

Note that `${PAR#WORD}` is non-greedy, and matches the shortest possible pattern - `${PAR##WORD}` matches the longest possible pattern. However, with `gpat="[%>#]"`, that will only match one character anyway:

```
# gpat="[%>#]" ;for f in *; do echo "$f" -- "${f##$gpat}"; done

%somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
#somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
%>#somefile.txt -- >#somefile.txt
% > #somefile.txt --  > #somefile.txt
```

If we have the `extglob` shell option set (check with `shopt extglob`, set with `shopt -s extglob`, unset with `shopt -u extglob` - it's probably set if you have a reasonable `bashrc`), we can use the extended globbing patterns:

```
# gpat="+([%>#])" ;for f in *; do echo "$f" -- "${f##${gpat}}"; done

%somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
#somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
%>#somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
% > #somefile.txt --  > #somefile.txt
```

Notably, though, in all the above examples, `"% > #somefile.txt"` becomes `" > #somefile.txt"` due to the space following the % not being captured by the pattern.

Of course, `${PARAMETER/PATTERN/STRING}` (and the `//` similar) also accept globbing patterns, but I've only realised this (literally) as I type these words, and I can't really be bothered going back through the above to adjust it to reflect that. Either way, it works exactly the same, and of course you'd only want to use `PAR/PAT/` to remove middle-of-string characters.

Comment: This works nicely on linux, unfortunately on OS X it seems to ignore it - which was where I intend using this. Thank you very much for the in-depth and insightful explanation; it's always nice to learn something :) (although I can't up-vote I give you a +2)

Comment: Ah, of course - I glossed over the OS X tag, sorry. After a quick bit of searching, it appears that the default OS X shell *might* not be `/bin/bash` - Could you provide the output of `echo $SHELL` and `bash --version`?

Comment: echo $SHELL = `/bin/bash` and bash --version = `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`

Comment: *Should* work, then... What's the output of `for f in *; do echo -- "$f" "${f//[%>#]/}"; done`?

Comment: Beautiful, that one works! tyvm :)

Comment: That's weird, because then the earlier lines should have worked as well - all the above line does differently is define the pattern in the expansion rather than deferring to a string variable. If you don't have extglobs set, or were using your original array variable instead of a globbing pattern, that would be a possible reason...

Answer (score 3):

this seems to work for me ...

```
$ ls
#somefile.txt  %somefile.txt  >somefile.txt

$ for f in *; do j=`echo $f | sed -e's/[\%\#\>]//g'`; echo "$f -- $j"; done
#somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
%somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
>somefile.txt -- somefile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there are way to do this while putting the regex pattern into an array? just curious.